# bash for loop with same order as GNU "ls -v" ("version-number" sort)

Tags: bash, for-loop

In a bash script I want to do a typical "for file in somedir" but I want the files to be processed in the same order that "ls -v" returns them. I know the downfalls of using "ls" as a function. Is there some way to replicate "-v" without using "ls"? Thanks.

Comment: The [POSIX standard for `ls`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ls.html) doesn't specify `-v` at all. This command isn't part of bash, but rather is provided by your OS vendor; since you haven't told us what your OS is, and the flag in question is not standardized, this question really needs more details.

Comment: If you're only cagey about `ls -v`. then you could use `ls -1 | sort -V`. Should be fairly portable..

Comment: @PaulHicks, better `printf '%s\0' * | sort -z -V`, to avoid misbehavior with filenames containing literal newlines or other mischief. And no, not so portable; `-V` isn't part of [POSIX `sort`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sort.html).

Comment: `ls -1` is fairly universal.. for my interest, where wouldn't it work?

Comment: @PaulHicks, `ls -1` is universal (POSIX-specified), but `sort -V` isn't. *However*, inasmuch as `ls -1` separates filenames with newlines, and filenames *are allowed to contain* newlines, while `ls -1` is universal, it isn't safe to use with arbitrary/unknown/attacker-controlled names.

Comment: `for i in $(find . -maxdepth 1 -print0 | sort -V -z - | xargs -0 -i echo {}); do echo $i; done` <--this can be hugely improved upon, possibly just by using xargs to do your work rather than a loop.

Comment: @zzxyz, [*ahem*](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor), [*ahem*](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Not reading the file.  I think I'm understanding the question differently.

Comment: @zzxyz, I didn't say anything about reading a file. You're parsing the output of the `find | sort | xargs` pipeline using word-splitting, which is exactly what the links in question apply to (whether content is from a file or not).

Comment: Oh right.  Defeats most of the purpose of using find -print0, doesn't it?

Comment: Would something like `find . -maxdepth 1 -print0 | sort -V -z - | xargs -0 -i cp {} $(basename {}).bak` for making backup copies of each file--not that you would need to do that in order--be reasonable if the loop wasn't a requirement?

Comment: @zzxyz, `$(...)` wouldn't be called once-per-`cp` in that form, so that syntax doesn't particularly work -- you'd have `basename {}` called once, *before* `xargs` runs, so the command would effectively be `xargs -0 -i cp {} {}.bak`. I'd consider `xargs -0 sh -c 'for arg; do cp "$arg" "${arg##*/}.bak"; done' _` or such, myself.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy It actually DOES work (I tested it), although now that you mention it, I'm not sure why :)

Comment: @zzxyz, are you sure `basename` is actually doing anything? If your files are coming the current directory, you wouldn't *notice* if it weren't -- the only point of having `basename` in that command is to make *backups* in the current directory, even if the *originals* are coming from somewhere else.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Derp, a good test for `basename` working is probably not files without extensions.  Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Would need different arguments to `basename` to get it to trim extensions anyhow -- as given it was trimming only leading directories, not trailing extensions (hence my assumption that that was your intent).

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that this is "version number" sort order, this is also implemented by GNU `sort`. Thus, on a GNU platform:

```
somedir=/foo
while IFS= read -r -d '' filename; do
  printf 'Processing file: %q\n' "$filename"
done < <(set -- "$somedir"/*; [[ -e $1 || -L $1 ]] && printf '%s\0' "$@" | sort -z -V)
```

If you *really* want to use a `for` loop rather than a `while` loop, parse into an array and iterate over that:

```
files=( )
while IFS= read -r -d '' filename; do
  files+=( "$filename" )
done < <(set -- "$somedir"/*; [[ -e $1 || -L $1 ]] && printf '%s\0' "$@" | sort -z -V)

for filename in "${files[@]}"; do
  printf 'Processing file: %q\n' "$filename"
done
```

---

To explain some of the magic above:

- In `< <(...)`, `<(...)` is a *process substitution*. It's replaced with a filename which, when read from, will return the output of the code enclosed. Thus, `< <(...)` will put that process substitution's output as the input to the `while read` loop. This loop form is described in [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001). The reasons to use this kind of redirection instead of piping into the loop are given in [BashFAQ #24](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024).
- `set -- "$somedir"/*` replaces the argument list within the current context (that context being the subshell running the process substitution!) with the results of `"$somedir"/*`; thus, (non-hidden, by default) contents of the directory named in the variable `somedir`.
- `[[ -e $1 || -L $1 ]]` is true only if that glob expanded to at least one item; if it remained `*` (and no actual filesystem object exists by that name), gating output on this condition prevents the process substitution from emitting any output.
- `sort -z` tells `sort` to delimit elements in both input and output with NULs -- a character that isn't allowed to exist in filenames.

Comment: Fantastic use of `\0` & `-z`. I would use `shopt -s nullglob` instead of the `-e||-L` test